# $\beta$-th moment of an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Let $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$ and $\beta > 0$. I'm figure how to find $\mathbb{E}[X^\beta]$, that is

$$\mathbb{E}[X^\beta] = \lambda \int_0^{+\infty}t^\beta e^{-\lambda t}  dt$$

I also know that an $\exp(\lambda)$ distribution can be seen as a $\Gamma(1, \lambda)$ distribution.

Since I know that for a $\Gamma(\alpha, \lambda)$ distribution it holds

$$\mathbb{E}[X^\beta] = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\lambda^\beta \Gamma(\alpha)}$$

therefore I would say that for $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$ I would obtain

$$\mathbb{E}[X^\beta] = \lambda \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\lambda^\beta} = \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\lambda^{\beta-1}}$$

But on textbook I have $\frac{\Gamma(\beta + 1)}{\lambda^\beta}$ as solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does $X\sim e^\lambda $ mean? Do you mean $X\sim e^{\lambda X}$? Pay attention to normalization and the sign of $\lambda$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to multiply by a factor of $\lambda$ again.

Since $$\mathbb{E}[X^\beta] = \lambda \int_0^{+\infty}t^\beta e^{-\lambda t}  dt$$ and
setting $\alpha=1$ we have $$\mathbb{E}[X^\beta] =  \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\lambda^\beta\Gamma(1)} = \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\lambda^{\beta}}.$$

---

Alternatively let $x=\lambda t$ (with $\lambda>0)$ then we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X^\beta] = \lambda \int_0^{+\infty}t^\beta e^{-\lambda t}  dt$$
$$=\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{x}{\lambda}\big)^{\beta}e^{-x}\frac{dx}{\lambda}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\lambda^{\beta}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\beta+1-1}e^{-x}dx$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\lambda^{\beta}}$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](http://Gamma%20function).